# How can I set isolation-level-for-create via yaml configuration file for spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I found a solution to do it via Java code here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobRepository

But, I want to do it if possible in a simple way via configuration in yaml format in the batch configuration file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is currently no such property in yaml available.

There is an open feature request in Spring Boot (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28802) that may result in a property like `spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create` in the future. Until then, you'll need to use Java (or XML) configuration.